# Is Nerve Growth Factor (NGF) commercially available?

Tags: neuroscience

I'm curious if NGF, or Neurotrophins in general is available commercially. Can I order it online? If not, what are the medical/biological reasons. Does it breakdown quickly after synthesis/capture? Is it a regulated protein?

Comment: No.  Any use in humans is strictly experimental and should only be done by physicians.  Using it like a nutritional supplement wouldn't do anything for the body anyway.

Comment: Nobel prize Rita Levi-Montalcini begs to differ: http://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/is-this-the-secret-of-eternal-life-1674005.html

Comment: It's awful hard to study something with an N=1.  Given that she put it in her eyes in the form of drops, it probably just degraded away.

Comment: (also, she *is* a physician)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not about biology but commerce, and is intrinsically temporarily transient.

Answer (score 3):

recombinant human NGF is available for purchase.  You might not be able to buy it without some sort of a research lab affiliation.

http://products.creative-biolabs.com/symbolsearch_NGF_1.htm